# Read only 8 characters from Serial Port

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port

Im trying to teach myself C Sharp with making an RFID reader.

I have created some code to read from a serial port (rfid reader over Bluetooth RS232)

The issue im hoping someone can help me with is that:

My RFID reader transmits the card code in very quick succession meaning when I swipe a card it will fire my event handler more than once with different sections of the card code so at the moment I cant receive a full card code in one hit making it impossible to process the card.

The code I have so far is:

```
    private SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM14", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); // set com port

    String code; // this stores the code from the RFID reader / serial port
    Int32 id; // this is the ID of the person that the RFID code belongs to
    String data;

    bool addtag;

    public Int32 ID // set the ID so it can be passed to other forms
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public rfidreader()
    {
        serialPort.DtrEnable = true; // enable data to flow from the SerialPort
        OpenSerialPort(); // Call the OpenSerialPort section below

        serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived); // when data is recieved from the RFID reader fire the event handaler
    }

    public void PauseRFIDReader()
    {
        addtag = false;
        OpenSerialPort();
    }

    public void CloseSerialPort()
    {
        serialPort.Close();
        addtag = true;
    }

    private void OpenSerialPort() // called from above
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort.Open(); // open the serialport
        }
        catch // if serail port unavalable show message box, if Retry is pressed run this section again, if cancel carry on without serial port
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to the RFID reader" + "\n" + "Check the reader is powered on and click Retry" + "\n\n" + "Press Cancel to use the program without RFID reader", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                OpenSerialPort(); // if retry is pressed run the sectiona gain
            }
            else
            {
            } 
        }
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // data recieved from RFID reader
    {
        if (addtag == false)
        {
            data = serialPort.ReadExisting(); // read what came from the RFID reader

            if (data.Length >= 9) // check if the string if bigger than 9 characters
            {
                code = data.Substring(0, 9); // if string is bigget than 9 characters trim the ending characters until it is only 9 long
            }
            else
            {
                code = data; // if less that 9 characters use however many it gets
            }
            MessageBox.Show(code.ToString());
            Start(); // start to process the person

        }
        else
        {  
        }
    }
```

Can anyone let me know how to limit the event handler from firing until 8 characters are received and only fire once a second?

Thanks in advance a very mind boggled Ryan

Comment: You can't really control how serial communication arrives, but you can buffer the incoming data until you have the whole message.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of using the buffer pleas?

Comment: You can use a StringBuilder and append incoming data to it until builder.Length >= 8, at which point you'd process the data and clear out the builder in preparation for the next scan.

Comment: You are overwriting data with the new incoming data. Instead of overwriting it, add to it. Instead of "data = serialPort.ReadExisting();" do "data += serialPort.ReadExisting()". And then when you process a chunk of data remove the data that you processed. Instead of using a string it would probably be better to use a byte or char buffer, array, or queue.

Comment: An RFID reader can almost always be configured to send a special character at the end of the string.  It probably already does, a linefeed is standard.  Which lets you use ReadLine(), now it is simple.

Comment: @HansPassant The reader I have is a RDM6300 which I believe sends a checksum 1. 9600bps,N,8,1
2. CHECKSUM: card 10byte DATA entire do XOR operation
02. How can I relate this to a linefeed? and infact does this send a line feed im unsure as  this is my first time with serial ports

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two different questions here:

1. How to read eight characters at a time.
2. How to limit processing of input to one card code every second.

The two can (and should) be addressed together. You can fix the first issue in your `DataReceived` event handler, but the exact details will depend on the second.

Unfortunately, your question says you want eight characters at a time, but your code says nine. So I have no way to ensure that detail is correct. I'll just add a constant, and let you decide. :)

I'd recommend something like this to handle the input:

```
private const _maxCharacters = 8;
private code = "";
private BlockingCollection<string> codes = new BlockingCollection<string>();

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (addtag == false)
    {
        data = serialPort.ReadExisting(); // read what came from the RFID reader

        while (data.Length > 0)
        {
            string fragment =
                data.Substring(0, Math.Min(maxCharacters - code.Length, data.Length));

            code += fragment;
            data = data.Substring(fragment.Length);

            if (code.Length == maxCharacters)
            {
                codes.Add(code);
                code = "";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {  
    }
}
```

Note that the above does not actually process the code. Instead, in order to accomplish the one-code-per-second design goal, you'll want to consume the codes outside of the above (introducing delays into the serial I/O itself will only cause problems).

So, in a different thread:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan minInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

private void CodeConsumer()
{
    TimeSpan lastCode = TimeSpan.MinValue;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    foreach (string code in codes.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        TimeSpan interval = sw.Elapsed - lastCode;

        if (interval < minInterval)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(minInterval - interval);
        }

        ProcessOneCode(code);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call `codes.CompleteAdding()` when you're done reading from the serial port, so the `CodeConsumer()` thread can exit.